# How is the ownership of a hacked account assigned back to the rightful owner, if the owner used made-up info to create the account?

Tags: account-security

Which information is utilized in the account recovery process, after an account hack, if all personal information used to create the account was made-up (such as a nickname) and it's impossible to assign the information to a physical person?

Specifically for a YouTube channel.

If both Gmail and Google accounts, which are needed to create the YouTube Channel, are created in a manner where all information submitted is made up and impossible to prove the ownership of,  by what does YouTube / Google identify me as the rightful owner of the channel?

Comment: you still have 2fa setup ?Use that to recover

Comment: @VipulNair if second factor can be used for recovery, then it's not a second factor.